# Angular file uplodad - specify file mask

Tags: html, angular

I need to specify file mask for upload. Upload window should accept only files with name ABC_????.xml.

Is this possible using standard Angular and HTML tools? Or is there any other file mask support in standard tools that at least partially solves my problem. I can't use any 3rd party libs.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using any AngularJS library or native javascript file upload?

Comment: I don't use AngularJS i use Angular and native upload component.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `accept` attribute of the file input.

```
<input type="file" accept=".xml" />
```

Answer (score 0):

AS per my understanding of your question, you want to allow only files that are start with `ABC_` and having `.xml` extension. so you can check with regex and return false.

```js
 

    function validateFile(elem){
        var regex = /^ABC_\w*.xml\b/;
        if(elem.value.match(regex )){
            return true;
        }else{
            alert("File must start with ABC_ and xml files are allowed.");
            elem.focus();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

```html
 <input type="file" onchange="validateFile(this)" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The regex should have 4 numbers but thats not point of this question. As I understand this is post check. I was hoping for passing the regex before to the window and that should not alow "Open" click unless choosen file matches regex. Something like <input type="file" accept=".xml" /> but extended with regex.